# in sql in a table, in a given column with data type text, how can we show the rest of the entries in that column after a particular entry

Tags: sql

in sql, in any given table, in a column named "name", wih data type as text
if there are ten entries, suppose an entry in the column is "rohit". i want to show all the entries in the name column after rohit. and i do not know the row id or id. can it be done??

Comment: How is "after" defined? I.e. after which column one has to sort to determines what record is after another?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select * from your_table where name > 'rohit'
```

but in general you should not treat text columns like that.
a database is more than a collection of tables.
think about how to organize your data, what defines a datarow.
maybe, beside their name, there is another thing how you would classify such a row? some things like "shall be displayed?" "is modified" "is active"?

so if you had a second column, say `display` of type `int` and your table looked like

```
CREATE TABLE MYDATA
    NAME TEXT,
    DISPLAY INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1);
```

you could flag every row with `1` or `0` whether it should be displayed or not and then your query could look like

```
SELECT * FROM MYDATA WHERE DISPLAY=1 ORDER BY NAME
```

to get your list of values.
it's not much of a difference with ten rows, you don't even need indexes here, but if you build something bigger, say 10,000+ rows, you'd be surprised how slow that would become!
in general, `TEXT` columns are good to select and display, but should be avoided as a `WHERE` condition as much as you can. Use describing columns, preferrably `int` fields which can be indexed with extreme high efficiency and an application doesn't get slower even if the record size goes over 100k.

Comment: oh wow thanks for downvoting a working sql command... how do i deserve that? based on the (spare) information in the question the only valid interpretation of "after" is an alphabetical approach. and this is exactly what above statement does. besides that, there is also nothing wrong in trying to help a beginner think about how to query. Commentless downvotes like this really reduce ANY motivation to help someone on this site almost down to zero...

Comment: utterly sorry grisgrahm, i have a nephew and he just played with the mouse,

Comment: i m trying to undo but it wont

Comment: the query is perfect and it runs just fine, thanx 4 helping me out,

Comment: Thanks for telling me why it happened and thanks for accepting the answer. Glad it works as you expected! Cheers, Gris

Answer (score -2):

You can use "default" keyword for it.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) DEFAULT 'rohit'
);
```